# localstorage not getting refreshed in angular service

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, angular-services

i am using angular 6 and `localStorage` for saving auth token.

the code which gets authtoken from localStorage is:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userdetails')).token
  })
};
```

and use it as

```
getCities() {
    return this.http.get<any>('http://myservice.com/api/cities', httpOptions);
  }
```

when i log out i am clearing `localStorage` and redirecting to home page as

```
localStorage.clear();
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

when i login, i am setting the `userdetails` localStorage item as

```
this.loginService.login(obj)
            .subscribe(
                auth => {
                                               localStorage.setItem('userdetails', JSON.stringify(auth));
                    this.router.navigate(['authentication/auth/redirectpage']);

                }
            );
```

My auth object i am saving is like this:

```
{"fullname":"Test User","username":"TestUser1","authlevel":"Q","designation":"Tester 1","token":"First_Login_Token"}
```

When i first login, everything is working fine. When i logout, `userdetails` localStorage element is getting destroyed (when checked in the Local Storage in Application tab of Chrome DevTools.

When i relogin with different user, my `userdetails` is getting updated properly to

```
{"fullname":"Test User 2","username":"TestUser2","authlevel":"R","designation":"Tester 2","token":"Second_Login_Token"}
```

**BUT**

`localStorage.getItem('userdetails')).token` in locationService returns `First_Login_Token` only.

> If i reload the page, it is properly taking `Second_Login_Token`.

Unsure of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue - this is the culprit:

```
const httpOptions
```

I have made it a variable in the class and am setting it in every method like:

```
export class LocationService {

  httpOptions: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  getcities() {
    this.httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userdetails')).token
      })
    };
    return this.http.get<any>('http://myservice.com/api/cities', this.httpOptions);
  }

.
.
.
```

Now, it's all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got nearly the same issue, found out the I called localStorage in the declaration part that's why it came null. You should declare the variable first then if you have localstorage call it after the constructor. Thanks Lakshman!

service.ts
header: any

constructor

header = localStorage....